# C# Help For Adding Radio Button / Options Button For MenuStrip

Tags: c#, radio-button, menustrip

I'm a beginner in C# language, so I need some help from the geniuses with this scheme: I need to add a radio button for a menu strip. I've already changed the, `CheckOnClick` property to `true`, but I need an option for radio button selection. You can see it from the `Windows` calculator menu bar (click View). 
How can I get to it via the `MenuStrip` property?

Comment: MSDN page: How to: Display Option Buttons in a MenuStrip (Windows Forms) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404318.aspx

Comment: but its not like radio option button

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a near-ancient post, but I thought it worth mentioning that although there's no native support for a RadioButton MenueItem, it's easy enough to coax their checkboxes into behaving that way. Start by setting the `CheckOnClick` property of each MenueItem to `FALSE`. Then apply the same `MouseDown` event handler to each item:

```
private void ToolStripMenueItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var thisTsmi = (ToolStripMenuItem)sender;
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem tsmi in thisTsmi.GetCurrentParent().Items)
    {
        tsmi.Checked = thisTsmi == tsmi;
    }
}
```

You could use the `Click` event instead, but I prefer `MouseDown` because it provides some visualization to the user that the checked item has changed while leaving the `Click` event open for coding the individual items if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404318.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404318.aspx)

you will see how it's done ;)!

Comment: Don"t you have a any easy option for just like changing the property option.

Comment: Changing a button you normally could just use the Selected propperty... I don't know exactly how it's done in your case tho.